# What's the effect of "int a(); " in C++?

Tags: c++

What's the effect of `int a();` in C++?

Is it equivalent to `int a` or `int a(0)`?

And how about `char c()` and `double d()`?

Answer (score 11):

> What's the effect of `int a();` in C++?

That declares a function, with no parameters, that returns an integer.

> Is it equivalent to `int a` or `int a(0)`?

No. Each of these declares a variable of integer type; the second also initialises it with the value zero.

> And how about `char c()` and `double d()`? Thanks.

These also declare functions, with different return types.

Answer (score 4):

`int a();` is a function declaration.

`int a` is declaring `a` to be of type `int`.

`int a(0)` is declaring a to be of type `int` and initialising it to `0`.

`char c()` and `double d()` are function declarations also returning `char` and `double` respectively.

All the function declarations should be terminated by a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it declares a function.

Comment: It's vexing, but it's not what's usually called "the most vexing parse"; that would be `int i(int())`;