# an instruction is being ignored in c++ and netbeans in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: c++, g++, sdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no call to the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor)
>   [What’s the effect of “int a(); ” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084710/whats-the-effect-of-int-a-in-c)
>   [What’s the differences between Test t; and Test t();? if Test is a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686298/whats-the-differences-between-test-t-and-test-t-if-test-is-a-class)

An instruction where i create an object is being ignored for some reason for a project of a game im trying to make.

The project is is just being started, i have no idea why is happening.

Im using netbeans as ide, g++ as the compiler and the OS is ubuntu 12.10.

the code where this is happening is this:

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include"Motor.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    Motor m1(); 
    return 0;
}
```

when i put a break point on "Motor m1();" and hit debug the arrow jumps to the return instruction after it and the constructor of the object is not executed

the code for Motor is this:

```
#include "Motor.h"
Motor::Motor() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    pantalla=NULL;
    pantalla=SDL_SetVideoMode(800,600,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);

    SDL_Delay(2000);
}
Motor::~Motor() {
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

the "SDL_Delay(2000)" is there for testing purposes.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `Motor m1();` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Motor m1();
```

This means that `m1` is a function that takes no parameters and returns an instance of class `Motor`.

You mean:

```
Motor m1;
```

This means to default construct an instance of class `Motor` and call it `m1`.